# How Can you add a variable inside do_shortcode("")

Tags: php, wordpress

So how would you add a variable inside a do_shortcode(''); Basically i have a variable holding a URL which is what I want to add inside the url attributte, but i am not sure how to do it.

This is what I tried so far

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[evp_embed_video url='"'. $video .'"' preload="auto" template="mediaelement"]'); ?>
```

but of course, it didn't work. Any advice on how to properly format this?

Comment: It looks like you're using quotes wrong. Try `<?php echo do_shortcode('[evp_embed_video url="'. $video . '" preload="auto" template="mediaelement"]'); ?>`

Comment: That worked! thank you!. I see what i did wrong now.